# Error calling MapViewOfFile

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use a function that requires a DWORD.

These are the specs:

> dwFileOffsetHigh [in]
>
> A high-order DWORD of the file offset where the view begins.
>   dwFileOffsetLow [in]
>
> A low-order DWORD of the file offset where the view is to begin. The
>   combination of the high and low offsets must specify an offset within
>   the file mapping. They must also match the memory allocation
>   granularity of the system. That is, the offset must be a multiple of
>   the allocation granularity. To obtain the memory allocation
>   granularity of the system, use the GetSystemInfo function, which fills
>   in the members of a SYSTEM_INFO structure.

The function fails for me with the error incorrect parameter.

```
unsigned long lByteStart=200959959;
unsigned long lByteLen=66964224;

MapViewOfFile( *phMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, lByteStart, lByteLen );
```

I did not care about high or low or low because I did not understand it and simply hoped it would work.

Now that it doesn't work, could somebody perhaps tell me what I did wrong and what I need to do to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the high/low part, you did that right. The problem is that 'the offset must be a multiple of the allocation granularity'. I don't think yours is.

A typical value for the allocation granularity is 4096 although you should check what it is on your system, as the quote says.

Comment: Granularity is 65536 bytes, not 64kb.

Comment: 65536 bytes and 64kb are the same thing, unless you're a Wikipedia editor :)

Comment: You also have to make sure that the mapping returned by `CreateFileMapping()` is large enough to accomodate the entire byte range being viewed or else the view will fail.